# .htaccess mod_rewrite - limit to root directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to apply a rule only to the root directory (where it's placed)?

Answer (score 0):

How about putting:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]*)
```

before any of your rules.  That will match on any number of characters that are not a slash.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]*(\?.*)?$
# your rewrite code here
```